# Codeigniter expressionEngine

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I just started working with codeigniter and i found it easy to work with. I recently came across expressionEngine and seems like a great add-on for codeigniter. My questions is, after i install expressionEngine,  will that change the way i work with codeigniter where code goes in controller and view in the view folder.

Answer (score 5):

Apples and Oranges,

Codeigniter is a framework that allows you to create a Web Application like an admin system. The customer does not add any content or touch anything. You can add CMS functionality to your codeigniter Web Application however in this sense you are actually building your own CMS on top of your Web Application.

ExpressionEngine, built with codeigniter, is a CMS that allows clients to add content without actually giving them access to your HTML - That is not to say that you can't give them access but this would defeat the purpose of a CMS.

Because expressionEngine is built on top of codeigniter it is possible to access it's functionality (I've seen posts on this but haven't tried it yet myself).

I think you would use the two together if you had a Web Application with a Website around it. In this way the client would be able to add content to the website and even some of the Application information areas but you would use Codeigniter to build the Web Application's functionality.

I don't think it would be a waste of a week to get into expressionEngine.  LevelUpTuts has some great video tutes on expressionEngine 2 and try Nettuts+ CodeIgniter from Scratch for, suprisingly, codeigniter.

(For those who are new to CMS) The general process of development is:
 - Translate your website design to HTML/CMS/jQuery
 - Translate your HTML to expresionEngine Templates
 - Define your Channels which your clients will add content to
 - Embed those Channels into your templates to display that content dynamically
 - In administration, assign permissions to who can add content to which channels for your clients

It will start to make sense once you try it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't layer ExpressionEngine on top of CodeIgniter since CodeIgniter is extracted from ExpressionEngine. It's EE all the way, or use CodeIgniter to build your own thing.

Comment: So if i want to put a custom php code, where does it go and how do we connect it with view

Comment: You can install ExpressionEngine and follow this tutorial to build your own controllers on top of EE's CodeIgniter base: http://paramoredigital.com/think/entry/harnessing-the-power-of-codeigniter-in-expressionengine-2.0/

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine supports PHP code [inside it's templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/php_templates.html) if that's what your asking.

EE(2.0) is a CMS built on the CI2.0 framework.

If you are familiar with CI you will be able to hack, modify and extend EE with ease, as well as develop your own plugins etc.

You can of course, have an EE installation *and* a CI installation on the same server, but the two do not interact directly - CI is a framework, EE is a CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I would call EE an "add-on"...

EE is it's own standalone Content Management System.  Generally EE and CI are not meant to be mixed.  While EE is built on CI, it is not meant to be extended/changed etc...  They (Ellislab) will tell you, [If EE doesn't fulfill your requirements, then you need to use CI exclusively.](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/88276/)

Plus, a 300$ license is pretty expensive for something that you view as an "add-on".

I would reccomend looking into [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com), which is also a free (beer and speech) CMS built on CI that directly allows for "Module" development which is straight codeigniter development with a few added meta/installation files that would allow you to build the extra functionality you need within the Codeigniter structure.

Answer (score 0):

There are four files for expression engine.
For Example i have module named "Products"
1)mcp.products for admin end or admin control panel just admin controller in pyrocms
2)mod.products front end code is placed here 3)tab.products tabs are here 4)upd.products installation code. There are views in "views" folder and model is in "model" folder in our case "products_model". Just copy your controllers methods and paste them in mcp.products.php on admin side. and copy your controllers methods and paste them in mod.products.php on front end side. in udp file place the table structure.and it will treat as you are in Pyrocms.